# Thumbnail field in Phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

In "Phpmyadmin", how can you have a "thumbnail field" ? This is NOT the ORIGINAL PHOTO that will be displayed on the site, but a "reference thumbnail" in the database. It would be very convenient to have that. (Look at my example picture ).

I do not want to use "BLOB field", which makes the database unnecessarily heavier. I am thinking of a link or an inserted  tag.

If "Phpmyadmin" does not do that, is there any software that does it ?
Thanks for your help.
[image: example]
<sub>(source: [bocquel.fr](http://www.bocquel.fr/admin2.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to store image pathnames instead in your DB, for quick and efficient delivery reasons. And for the thumbnail case, I would use a separate image with much less quality and so weight. Hope I help you! :)

Comment: Image path names are, of course, stored in the database ! What I show as on my image is only a very very simplified example ! But you speak of a "separate image" in very low quality, and that's exactly what I'm looking for ! ... so, how would you do that, without of course using "BLOB" or "TINYBLOB" ?

Comment: You can use JavaScript it makes you display what you are looking for using the an image. With: `window.URL.createObjectURL()`  :)  link (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) at the end